# search collection by index in JPA @query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities with OneToMany Relation as below,

```
    public class Visit{
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "visit", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @OrderBy("updated_on DESC")
       private List<StatusChange> statusHistory;
    }

    public class StatusChange{
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "ms_visit_id")
      private Visit visit;

      @Column(name = "to_status")
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      private VisitStatus toStatus;
   }
```

Visits can have multiple status like created, canceled, deleted etc.. whenever the status change there will be a new row added to the StatusChange table with a entry associated to that visit (toStatus will become canceled) . Now I want a query to filter the visits for which the latest status is canceled and with the matching user id.

I am using the @query of JPA. I already have got the result with the following query.

```
@Query(value = "select vs1.visit from StatusChange vs1 where vs1.id in (" +
        " select max(vs2.id) from StatusChange vs2 " +
        " where vs2.visit.user.id = :userId" +
        " group by vs2.visit.id)" +
        " and vs1.toStatus in :status")
public List<MSVisit> findByUserAndStatus(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("status") List<Visit.VisitStatus> status);
```

But I feel the query can be improved  or is there any way to query some thing like,

```
"from Visit visit" +
            " where visit.statusHistory.get(0).toStatus in :status" +
            " and visit.user.id = :userId
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, these queries are best modeled with lateral joins, but Hibernate does not support that yet. Note that unless you meant something different, your query is not correct, as the max-aggregation is based on the value of the id rather than the updated_on value. Not sure if that is on purpose, but I would suggest the following query in case you really want the latest visit.

```
@Query(value = "from Visit vs1 where vs1.user.id = :userId and (select max(h.updatedOn) from vs1.statusHistory h) >= ALL (" +
        " select max(h.updatedOn) from vs1.statusHistory h " +
        " and vs1.toStatus in :status")
public List<MSVisit> findByUserAndStatus(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("status") List<Visit.VisitStatus> status);
```